# How to send an email in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want (as an admin) to send an email to an user when i delete him from the db !!
who knows how to do this thing !!
 and this is my destroy func

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $thisuser = User::find($id);
    $thisuser->delete();
    Mail::send('admin.mails.activate', array_merge($data, ['user' => $user]), function ($message) use ($user) {
        $message->to($user->email)->subject('Account Deleted')->from('nesrinems97@gmail.com');
    });
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Please write some code so we can help you with a more specific issue.

Comment: No question, no answer. What have you tried, what has failed and why? Please provide some code. SO is not a board, where you can request others to write code for you or guide you how to do.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher i updated my question

Comment: You have several issues here: `$data` and `$user` are never defined, so it makes it impossible for it to send. I'm guessing you mean to make an empty `$data` array, and merge `$thisuser` with it, not `$user`. Though you really don't need to do that if `$data` is just an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside this function in your User model, it will be called automatically when a User is deleted:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    //catch delete
    static::deleting(function ($model) {
        $data = '...'; //(you still need to define this)
        Mail::send('admin.mails.activate', array_merge($data, ['user' => $model]), function ($message) use ($model) {
            $message->to($model->email)->subject('Account Deleted')->from('nesrinems97@gmail.com');
        });
    });
}
```